# How to get only last actual output

Tags: java, neural-network, encog

My data consists of 3 inputs variables (double), and 1 output. 
I am training with around 20,000- 50,000 rows of data. 
This code show me every input,actual output and ideal output.

```
for(MLDataPair pair: trainingSet ) {
        final MLData output = network.compute(pair.getInput());
        System.out.println(pair.getInput().getData(0) + "," + pair.getInput().getData(1)+","+pair.getInput().getData(2)
                + ", actual=" + output.getData(0) + ",ideal=" + pair.getIdeal().getData(0));
    }
```

I would like to get only last actual output. Only one last value.
How to write this code? Can somebody write it to me please.

Comment: Just access the last index of the array that's returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int i = 0;
    for(MLDataPair pair: trainingSet ) {
    i++;
    final MLData output = network.compute(pair.getInput());
    if(i == trainingSet.size()-1){
         System.out.println("actual=" + output.getData(0));
       }
    }
```